# USD - Scriptlets can they take an argument?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, unified-service-desk

Is there a way to pass an argument to a Scriptlet?  So my replacement parameter would be like [[script.scriptname("blah")]] and the scriptlet would be:

````
function a(b){
  <do something with b>
  return something;
}
a(<string I passed in>)```
````

Answer (score 0):

The value of "blah" is almost certainly coming from some other replaceable parameter, correct?  If so, just initialize it within the scriptlet function.  This is an effective way of "passing parameters" into Scriptlets and script-type Action Calls (RunScript and RunXrmCommand).

```
function myScriptletFunction() {
    var someVariable = "[[ValueOfBlah]]";
    // Do Stuff with someVariable of "blah"
}
myScriptletFunction();
```

Comment: Right but I am working in the XAML for the Account Session lines and displaying dozens of fields from D365 and I don't want to have a scriptlet for every field.  There's some logic I need to apply for every field, so I was hoping I could utilize one scriptlet via passing in value.

Comment: Unfortunately, replacement parameters for scriptlets refer to the scriptlet record name, not the name of any function therein. You can pass parameters into scriptlet functions, yes, but not via replacement syntax. Instead of trying to complicate your implementation by searching for a viable solution involving fewer config records, you may want to resign yourself to having a large number of records as required by a known viable solution.